# get_post_meta - get a single value

Tags: post-meta

When I do `get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", false)` I am getting back an array of key/values pairs.

```
array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'f_name' => string 'John Doe' (length=14)
          'f_company_name' => string 'Something Ltd' (length=0)
          'f_description' => string '' (length=0)
          'f_phone' => string '0208 992 7222' (length=13)
          'f_cell_phone' => string '07809775200' (length=0)
          'f_email' => string 'jonh.doe@gmail.com' (length=0)
          'f_web' => string 'doe.com' (length=0)
```

**How to get a single value for example `f_name`?**

just FYI everything is taking place inside `foreach loop`:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'company'
);

$posts = get_posts($args);  


foreach ($posts as $post){ 

    // do stuff

}
```

Comment: Array can be serilaized while inserting into database, you can use just get_post meta and store it in a variable and use it like array.  http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/06/get_post_meta-example/

Answer (score 6):

If every meta value has the key `f_name`

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", true);
echo $meta['fname'];
```

If you're not sure of the contents & want to search for the first one available

```
$name = false;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", false);
foreach($meta as $array) {
    if(isset($array['f_name'])) {
        $name = $array['f_name'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $name;
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without using variable? `get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", true)->key` ??

Comment: You can't use `get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", true)->key` since the return value from the function is not an object but an array but you can probably typecast it to object & then use it `((object)get_post_meta($post->ID, "company_wp_box_g", true))->key`